# Can a python file run on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, bottle

I have developed a webserver in Python (using Bottle). In this moment it runs on my laptop, but in future it will run on a board (like Raspberry). 
The webserver shows a html page that allow to the users to put some data and it should save locally in a file. 
Is it possible? I have to use php?

Thanks

Comment: you can install python on a raspberry pi. Just google it.

Comment: No, why would you think you need to use PHP? Bottle is already a web framework.

Comment: Simple google search about using Python on the Raspberry Pi would have been a better option than posting here. http://raspberry.io/wiki/how-to-get-python-on-your-raspberrypi/

Comment: The question is "I have to save locally a file with the data inserted. On the board I have to install a PHP interpreter?"

Comment: @lucacatr why do you think that repeating the question in the comments will achieve anything? Python can be used to save files, just like any programming language. Again, read the links you've been given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just run your python apps on a Raspberry Pi. There are many tutorials on the web.

### Video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VFs1dhJPYa4

### Tutorials:

- https://makezine.com/projects/program-raspberry-pi-with-python/
- http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/10-raspberry-pi-projects-beginners/
- http://www.techradar.com/news/software/learn-to-program-your-raspberry-pi-1148194/2

Comment: The question is "I have to save locally a file with the data inserted. On the board I have to install a PHP interpreter?"

Comment: @lucacatr if you just read any of the tutorials you would have your answer. 3 of us have already told you that you don't need PHP.